# how to concatenate multiple NSData?

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, nsmutabledata, external-accessory

My problem is the next> I have to receive data from an external accessory and save it into a big `NSData`, each time I receive a stream I have to copy that `NSData` into another one:

```
CompleteNSData = NSDataTx1 + NSDataTx2 + NSDataTx3;
```

and at the end show the whole info to the user.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Edited** since the question was changed:

If you need to concatenate multiple `NSData` objects into one then something like this will work:

```
NSData *data1 = ... // the 1st NSData object
NSData *data2 = ... // the 2nd NSData object
NSData *data3 = ... // the 3rd NSData object
NSMutableData *completeData = [data1 mutableCopy];
[completeData appendData:data2];
[completeData appendData:data3];
```

Call `appendData:` for each `NSData` you need to append.

Comment: addProSig and addAct are used for...? sorry I'm new on this.

Comment: I have no idea. Those are the methods you posted in your question. If you don't know what they are then you have bigger issues. :)